# print js variable into innerHTML call in another js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-table

Basically I have two javascript files that are separated but linked to a single html file. In this html file, in the js sections (i.e script section) I have declared a variable which I would like to print in an innerHTML part of the other js file where I am currently making a table.

Here I declared the variable in the script section of the html file:

```
 var varIwanttoprint = 'data/rnase.mtz'
```

Here is the code for the table

```
var tab1 = document.getElementById("tab1");
tab1.innerHTML ='<p><hr></p><h3>General data</h3>' +
'<table class="table-blue">'+
'<tr><td>Path</td><td>**The variable i want to print here**</td></tr>'
```

However, I can't seem to find a way to print the js value of the js variable inside the html table. Is there any way I can do this?

Thank you

Comment: if the `innerHTML` part of the code is in a function, then you can call the function and pass the variable as an argument.

Comment: What syntax would I need to put the variable into the '<tr><td> XXXX </tr></td> part of the innerHTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the **innerHTML** part of the code is in a function then you can pass the value as an argument.

If innerHTML not in a function make sure the js file which including the **innerHTML** code is bellow the script section of **varIwanttoprint** and then you can concatenate the value.

```
var tab1 = document.getElementById("tab1");
tab1.innerHTML ='<p><hr></p><h3>General data</h3>' +
'<table class="table-blue">'+
'<tr><td>Path</td><td>'+varIwanttoprint+'</td></tr>'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Because innerHTML was within another function, passing the variable I want to print as a parameter managed to fix it

Comment: Also, declaring it as a global variable seems to work as well

Comment: Happy to know that it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

**1st way**

```
function retrunParam(){
var varIwanttoprint = 'data/rnase.mtz';return varIwanttoprint;

}


var tab1 = document.getElementById("tab1");
tab1.innerHTML ='<p><hr></p><h3>General data</h3>' +
'<table class="table-blue">'+
'<tr><td>Path</td><td>'+retrunParam()+'</td></tr>'
```

**2nd way**

```
var tab1 = document.getElementById("tab1");
tab1.innerHTML ='<p><hr></p><h3>General data</h3>' +
'<table class="table-blue">'+
'<tr><td>Path</td><td id="replaceHere">**The variable i want to print here**</td></tr>'

 var varIwanttoprint = 'data/rnase.mtz'
document.getElementById("replaceHere").innerHTML = varIwanttoprint;
```